How do I type a method in base class that returns another class instance that is defined in child class?
Imaging a base class BaseA with method get_b that returns an instance of class B. Class B is defined in both BaseA and another class Child that inherits from BaseA.
class BaseA:
  def get_b(self):
    return self.B()
  
  class B:
    pass


class Child(BaseA):
  class B(BaseA.B):
    def hello(self):
      return "hello"


Child().get_b().hello()

When this is run get_b on an instance of Child will return an instance of B from Child and runs as expected, but Pyright says the return type of get_b is BaseA.B and all extended methods are not available.
Gets this pyright error:
Diagnostics:
1. Cannot access attribute "hello" for class "B"
     Attribute "hello" is unknown [reportAttributeAccessIssue]

Is there any way to type hint this correctly?

What you want depends on the dynamic (run-time) type of self, not a static type.

I do not use pyright, so I will not get in detail with pyright implementation details.
More generic, this is a problem between static type iferring and real runtime types.
For most static typecheckers, and probably also for pyright, the type of self in your get_b method is always a direct instance of BaseA. Therefore the inferred type of get_b is always BaseA.B.
But in runtime the type of self is the real instance where the method is bound to. So for BaseA().get_b() this is an instance of BaseA. But for Child().get_b() self is of type Child and not BaseA.
And because local namespaces are checked for more global namespaces, the expression self.B() for an instance of Child returns an instance of Child.B because this is the more local defined value for the name B.
tldr
This is a problem of your static type checker. Not of your runtime.
possible solution
As I have noted above, I do not have pyright, so this is untested.
Maybe you can get rid of the problem, by helping your static typechecker by adding the correct return type manually, instead of reling on static code analysis that always does not recognize every runtime hack.
from __future__ import annotations

class BaseA:
    def get_b(self) -> BaseA.B:
        return self.B()

    class B:
        pass


class Child(BaseA):
    class B(BaseA.B):
        def hello(self):
            return "hello"
        
    def get_b(self) -> Child.B:
        return super().get_b()


But, as you can see, this are more lines of code. So it depends on your project requirements, if it is better to make the static typechecker happy or to reduce the lines of code.
